# My script keeps on printing even when nothing is left

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, openpyxl

I've written a script in python using `openpyxl` to get some `names` and its correspoding `values` from `Sheet1` and use them as parameters meant to be passed in an url to make it a valid url. The problem is when I run my script, it keeps on printing urls even when there are only 5 of them in `Sheet1`. So far my knowledge goes, the way I defined `max row` is accurate. How the max row becomes unlimited?

This is the script:

```
import requests
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook('ReverseSearch.xlsx')
ws = wb['Sheet1']

def search_name(session,query,query1):
    session.headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"}
    res = session.get(url.format(query,query1))
    print(res.url)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = "https://www.yellowpages.com/los-angeles-ca/mip/{}-{}"
    for row in range(2, ws.max_row + 1): #I used row 2 cause there are headers in row 1
        key = ws.cell(row=row,column=1).value
        key1 = ws.cell(row=row,column=2).value
        session = requests.Session()
        search_name(session,key,key1)
```

`names` I used:

```
café claude
sears fine food
chaat cafe
bean bag coffee house
primo patio cafe
```

`values` I used:

```
3392129
473113343
18528177
12192803
641231
```

I'm supposed to get only 5 links (fully qualified) but Im getting blank urls when there are no parameters left.

```
https://www.yellowpages.com/san-francisco-ca/mip/cafe-claude-3392129?lid=3392129
https://www.yellowpages.com/san-francisco-ca/mip/sears-fine-food-473113343?lid=473113343
https://www.yellowpages.com/san-francisco-ca/mip/chaat-cafe-18528177?lid=18528177
https://www.yellowpages.com/san-francisco-ca/mip/bean-bag-coffee-house-12192803?lid=12192803
https://www.yellowpages.com/san-francisco-ca/mip/primo-patio-cafe-641231?lid=641231
https://www.yellowpages.com/los-angeles-ca/mip/None-None
https://www.yellowpages.com/los-angeles-ca/mip/None-None
https://www.yellowpages.com/los-angeles-ca/mip/None-None
```

I wish my script stops when 5 links are printed.

Btw, this is how the url looks like:

```
url = "https://www.yellowpages.com/los-angeles-ca/mip/{}-{}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would put this as a comment but I don't have enough rep.

My first trouble shooting step would be to check what you get if you do?

```
print(ws.max_row)
```

Does it print 7?

If it prints a bigger number it might be counting empty rows in your document, in that case you would need to check the content of your cells a break the loop

Comment: There is your problem, either you find a way to fix your row count or you break your loop when you hit an empty cell

Comment: Yes, using this `if query and query1:` condition I can get desired results. However, can you tell me why I'm getting that big row count even when they are empty?

Comment: That part I am not sure, probably when openpyxl reads the excel file, it sees 652 rows even if most of them are empty. Try going in your Excel file, selecting all the rows you dont need and do a right click delete?

Comment: You led me to the right direction. Actually, I created that `.xlsx` workbook manually. When I create a workbook using `openpyxl` and read the max row then it gives me the right row count.

Comment: If you find out this weird behavior (reading wrong count), feel free to drop here a comment. Thanks.